# Using map in a multidimensional array Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this set of data that I'm trying to convert to map:

```
x = [
    {
        food: 'Steak',
        ingredients: [
            {
                item1: 'pepper',
            },
            {
                item2: "salt",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        food: 'Veggies'
    },
    {
        food: 'Fruits'
    },
];
```

This is my current `map` function, question is how do I iterate on the ingredients?:

```
<div>
    {Object.keys(x).map(key => (
        <a key={key}>{x[key].food}</a>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: `x` is an array, so you can map it directly. no need for `Object.keys`. The ingredients is also an array although with a weird format. It would be better for `ingredients` to be an array of strings or at least objects with the same schema. No need to change the name of the ingredient `item` property

Comment: Yes, I agree with above comment. And what you want to do after iteratiing `ingredients` array. means want to add an html element or what ?

Comment: Yes add it to an HTML element

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli can you please show me the better format for `ingredients`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
x = [
    {
        food: 'Steak',
        ingredients: [
            {
                item1: 'pepper',
            },
            {
                item2: "salt",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        food: 'Veggies'
    },
    {
        food: 'Fruits'
    },
];

const list = x.map(item => 
    ({[item.food]: item.ingredients ? 
        item.ingredients.flatMap(i =>      
        Object.keys(i).map(k => 
            i[k])).join(','): 'no ingredients'}))

console.log(list)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Steak": "pepper,salt"
  },
  {
    "Veggies": "no ingredients"
  },
  {
    "Fruits": "no ingredients"
  }
]
```

A better format for the data:

```
x = [
    {
        food: 'Steak',
        ingredients: [
             "pepper", "salt",
        ],
    },
    {
        food: 'Veggies'
    },
    {
        food: 'Fruits'
    },
];
```

Naming things is 80% of programming. The other 20% is choosing the right font for your IDE.

If you have an array of objects and the key of object holds no semantic meaning, and there is one key in each object, that's a sign that it should be an array.

You could go one step further:

```
const ingredients = {
  Steak: ["pepper", "salt"],
  Veggies: []
  Fruits: []
};
```

The name of the data structure makes sense. It is an "ingredients by food" object.

Where you went off is starting with `x` as the name of the object. `x` is an unknown. Start by describing everything clearly, and use JetBrains Mono.

If you want to easily iterate over the object using `map` (like to render a table in React), then you could do:

```
const ingredients = [
  {Steak: ["pepper", "salt"]},
  {Veggies: []},
  {Fruits: []}
];
```

or:

```
const recipes = [
  {food: Steak, ingredients: ["pepper", "salt"]},
  {food: Veggies, ingredients: []},
  {food: Fruits, ingredients: []}
];
```

(which is close to the reduction I did to your original data)

That one should be called `recipes`, which I discovered when I wrote this next function and the names didn't make sense if the object were named `ingredients`.

```
recipes.forEach(recipe => {
   console.log(`HTML Title: %{recipe.food})
   console.log(`HTML Subtitle: Ingredients`)
   recipe.ingredients.forEach(ingredient => 
      console.log(`* ${ingredient}`)
   )
})
```

See, the names in the data structure make sense, and so do the functions to work with it. And the data structure itself is small and comprehensible. Structure is also data.

JetBrains Mono.

Comment: What if I need to have another nested array on the ingredients?

Comment: No problem: what is it called?

Comment: Say I have this:

`
ingredients:
    curry:
        powder,
        flavoring,
        coloring
`

Comment: What is that called? I get that the curry is an "ingredient". What is the sub-array called?

Comment: What do you mean called? I'll name it as an additive of that particular ingredient

Comment: No, that's not the right name. Once you get the name right, the data structure will be obvious. Are these qualities that the ingredient adds to the food? Or are these further characteristics of the ingredient, like the `ingredient.type`? Like a sub-typing?

Comment: We can say it like that

Comment: If that is the case - are these ingredients reused between different recipes? Strings you have to put in line, but if you have complex objects for green curry and yellow curry, then are you going to duplicate them in your data structure, or have another structure with the ingredients and point to them? At render time you will have to build the entire populated structure. But for storage and updating them, you might have one instance of each ingredient in its own data structure, and a pointer.

Comment: Regardless, I would call them `recipes.ingredients.attributes`, and code it using Jetbrains Mono. Feel free to mark my answer as the solution if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can store all ingredientItem in one array and then apply Map on that array:

```
let ingredientItem = [];
x.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.ingredients) {
        item.ingredients.forEach((ingredient) => {
            for (name in ingredient) {
                ingredientItem.push(ingredient[name])
            }
        })
    }
})

ingredientItem.map((item) => {

})
```